# mockResolvedValue is not a function on partial mock with Jest/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to partially mock a module, and set the return value for the mocked method as needed in certain tests.

Jest is throwing this error:

```
mockedEDSM.getSystemValue.mockResolvedValue is not a function
TypeError: mockedEDSM.getSystemValue.mockResolvedValue is not a function
```

My mock:

```
jest.mock('../src/models/EDSM', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual<typeof import('../src/models/EDSM')>('../src/models/EDSM'),
  getSystemValue: jest.fn(),
}));
const mockedEDSM = jest.mocked(EDSM);
```

Within tests:

```
it('should test', () => {
  mockedEDSM.getSystemValue.mockResolvedValue(edsmData);
});
```

Typescript is throwing no warnings in the IDE, I'm only getting errors from Jest when running the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah of course, found the answer right after posting this!

No need to call `jest.mock` at the top of the test file, the only thing needed is to spyOn the method within each test (or in a before/after hook):

```
const getSystemValueMock =
  jest.spyOn(EDSM, 'getSystemValue')
  .mockResolvedValue(edsmData);
```